# How to combine multiple click events that pass value into one?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following code that I pass a single parameter for each button click event for my game level menu.

```
    private void btnLevelVeryEasy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePlay.xaml?parameter=0", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btnLevelEasy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePlay.xaml?parameter=1", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btnLevelMedium_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePlay.xaml?parameter=2", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btnLevelHard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePlay.xaml?parameter=3", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btnLevelInsane_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePlay.xaml?parameter=4", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

My question is, how to do it more elegantly by having all the buttons fire one click event and pass unique parameter? Something like

```
    private void btnLevel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePlay.xaml?parameter=[buttontag]", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sayse almost got it right, except the .Name should be after the ():

```
string buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;

            switch (buttonName)
            {
                case "button1":
                    MessageBox.Show("Button1 pressed");
                    break;
                case "button2":
                    MessageBox.Show("Button2 pressed");
                    break;
            }
```

EDIT:

OP, you do know how to link the event on each button do you? (In events just click the dropdown menu and select the previous created event)

Comment: true, darn you early mornings!

Comment: @Sayse Yeah mornings are the worst :P

Comment: If you don't want to tie the button names to the logic you can use the Tag property instead of the Name property

Answer (score 2):

Futher to my comment, depending on how your buttons have been named you may be able to use

```
string buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;
```

with button being your button class

and then parsing this string to get the number that has been included in your name...

for example

```
string lastChar = buttonName[buttonName.length - 1];
```

edit If you wish to keep the names the same then you can use a switch statement

```
string s;
switch(((Button)sender).Name)
{
case "btnLevelEasy":
s = "1";
break;
```